# How do I clear an input field on a form using Java - Selenium combo

Tags: java, selenium

So I am trying to write something in Java where I can do the following:

```
Login with bad email or password, click submit
Return error message
Then while on the same page 
CLEAR or send new text (correct email and password) 
And Submit
```

I have the bad Login using bad email and password portion done. 
It's the bottom portion I am struggling with. 
I have tried the following:

```
 driver.findElement(By.name("login_email")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a"),"email@gmail.com" );
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_password")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a"), "password");
```

and another variation where I create an Element using :

```
WebElement email = driver.findElement......
WebElement password = driver.findElement.....
email.sendKeys....
password.sendKeys.....
```

This is all so that I can create an automated script (obviously) to replace the text in the field for a login that is using Form on web page. I am using JAVA for no reason other than I can understand it and currently can't update the selenium pkg to fix a bug in Python. I have been searching and searching so if anybody can help me out. I am a noob so do a good deed =)

Comment: Check [element.clear()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#clear--)

Comment: thanks i'm gonna make a point to use this site more often.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try using `clear()` ?

```
WebElement email = driver.findElement......
WebElement password = driver.findElement.....
email.clear();
email.sendKeys....
password.clear();
password.sendKeys.....
```

Comment: *palm to face wipe* i did a variation of sendkeys() and other things - it never freaking crossed my mind. Thank you  - it worked.

Comment: Like I said I'm new to this and trudging along.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the `clear()` method isn't working, in this case, we can use an alternative way, using `org.openqa.selenium.Keys`:

```java
     element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.DELETE));
```

A harder solution (and I don't count this is a good approach) is using a java.awt.Robot framework:

```java
int x = element.getLocation().getX();
int y = element.getLocation().getY();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(x, y);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
```